# A mathematical question on error detection

Tags: computer-networks

For a bit of context, I was going through the previous year questions of my college computer networks course and found this in one of the papers. I don't even know how to go about solving this problem, it would be really helpful if someone could help me with this.

The question goes as follows:

Justify the validity of following statement:

"If x^2 bit dataword is encoded with two dimensional parity check code having x + 1 rows then it is possible to correct upto x bit errors"

Comment: "x ^ 2 bit dataword" doesn't make the slightest bit of sense to me.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think what they meant was for an integer x, the dataword size is x^2 and the number of rows are x + 1, making the total size x^2 * (x + 1)

Comment: Can you add the details of the  two dimensional parity check? I'm surprised it can even **detect** (let alone **correct**) $4$ bit errors (think of errors lying in a 2x2 submatrix, no row or column parity is affected).

Comment: @Steven, you say 4 bit error i.e., x = 4. In that case, number of rows and columns would be 5 and 16 respectively.

Comment: Pick $x = 5$ (or any $x \ge 5$) and consider a $4$-bit error corresponding to a $2 \times 2$ submatrix. If this error is not detectable (as I suspect but cannot confirm until you share the details of the code) this contradicts the claim.

Comment: (I think it was meant to be x+1 rows as well as columns, with maybe one more parity bit thrown in.) There got to be more course material than just questions (& possibly answers).